# How to know whether outgoing call is answered or rejected in android programmatically

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I am working on a call Dialer demo. In that I have made a receiver for listening call events.

Now I want to know if person on other side answer or reject my call and based in that i want to change the screens. I.e. if call is answered it should got to **ScreenA** and if rejected it should go to **ScreenB**.

I have tried as below with no luck:

```
 else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            // This code will execute when the call is disconnected

            if(IncomingCall.call_resp.equals("1")){
                Intent i=new Intent(context , CallScreen.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                context.startActivity(i);
            }else {
                Intent i=new Intent(context , MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can take a look at the Related posts at the bottom right, though there doesn't seem to be a solution to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: @asgs-Thank you so much for your valuable comment..!